Flutter Firebase android app does not launch
i have a weird problem, app launches on chrome. But on android device  stacks and says "Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode..."
I read almost every question on stack over flow, could not find any solution.
Wiped Simulator cache
re created build.gradle etc.
Here is my Main.dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomeScreen(),
      theme: lightMode,
    );
  }
}



Just try to run your app in a real device.

Make sure you have downloaded the google-services.json file from your firebase project,
wait to download all gradle
